# Does the measured temperature of a body depends on the specific heat capacity of the material inside the thermometer we are using?

Tags: thermodynamics

Since the rise of temperature in a body is measured by its specific heat capacity, will my measurement of a body's temperature changes if i use a different thermometer rather than the usual mercury thermometer

Comment: The body will have a heat capacity much greater than that of the thermometer, so the thermometer will not significantly affect the measurement.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. But first, about your title : "specific heat of the material". A material cannot have heat or specific heat. Did you mean "specific heat capacity of the material"?

Comment: @EricDuminil [specific heat](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/thermo/spht.html) is another term used for specific heat capacity.

Comment: Oh okay. Thanks for the comment, I've never encountered this term before. Too many people use temperature and heat interchangeably, and saying "specific heat" instead of "specific heat capacity" might not help much from a pedagogical point of view.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Since the rise of temperature in a body is measured by its specific
> heat capacity

That is incorrect.

Suppose we have a very large heat source, at a **constant** temperature $T_{\infty}$. Now we insert a much smaller object, at a different temperature, say $T_0$.

The Laws of Thermodynamics state that *given enough time* the temperature of the smaller body will become equal to the temperature of the large heat source.

This outcome in *no way depends on the heat capacity* of either body or other factors. Heat capacity, mass and other factors *can* influence greatly the *rate* at which the smaller object tends to $T_{\infty}$ (see e.g. [Newton's Law of Cooling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_law_of_cooling#Mathematical_formulation_of_Newton%27s_law)), but not the final temperature.

This is true also if both objects are of more comparable sizes and of different temperatures, say $T_1$ and $T_2$. Given enough time, both will exchange heat, heat flowing from hot to cold, until they both reach the same end temperature $T_e$, where:

$$T_1<T_e<T_2$$

(assuming $T_2>T_1$)

Comment: heat capacity and specific heat capacity both are different right? Heat capacity is extensive while specific heat capacity is intensive. And if what you said is true then there should be no need to define a fixed point(triple point of water)

Comment: Why would there no need to define a triple point, IYO?

Comment: @SpacemanSpiff How is using a thermometer related to the triple point of water? By the definition of Kelvin? Thermometers had been used even before Kelvin was defined…

Comment: @SpacemanSpiff Specific heat capacity is not a parameter that can be associated to a thermometer in a meaningful way because a thermometer is not a homogeneous material. The parameter of interest is the heat capacity, whose only effect is that of changing the time constant with which the thermometer will reach the equilibrium with the measurand system.

Comment: *And if what you said is true* You can verify the veracity of my claims easily at home, with simple experiments.

Comment: @EricDuminil I'm not sure why you're trying to lecture me. For what it's worth I of course agree with you because what you write is quite trivial.

Comment: I removed my previous comments. What still bothers me is : "**Heat capacity**, mass and other factors can influence greatly the rate at which the smaller object tends to T∞, **but not the final temperature**." And directly afterwards : "**This is true** also if both objects are of more comparable sizes and of different temperatures". The final temperature does depend on the heat capacity of both objects, so the former statement cannot be true for this case. Just to be clear: I'm not trying to lecture you or doubt your knowledge. I'm simply mentioning that the last paragraph is confusing.

Answer (score -1):

No, It depends up on the scale you are using to measure the temperature.
With different material inside thermometer, the shown temperature will depend on the calibration of the scale with respect to that material